# Resampling error with pandas dataframe datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, pandas-resample

I am running a txt. file through python and trying to resample the data into daily averages. The txt. file contains text before the actual data set, so I read the file then deleted the first rows. The entire data set has ~3 million rows.

Sample data looks like this:

```
**There are 20 lines of text before the data           

     Date      Time             Time           Pressure     Temperature
   M/d/yyyy  HH:mm:ss            hr              psi            degF
  
  10/23/2019  16:39:25        0.000000         13.3120        106.0533
  10/23/2019  16:39:26        0.001389         13.2860        106.0155
  10/23/2019  16:39:27        0.002778         13.2952        105.9848
  10/23/2019  16:39:28        0.004167         13.2788        105.9535
  10/23/2019  16:39:29        0.005556         13.2704        105.9228
  10/23/2019  16:39:30        0.006944         13.2946        105.8922
  10/23/2019  16:39:31        0.008333         13.2684        105.8620
```

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('well_pressures.txt', header=None)
df.drop(df.head(20).index, inplace=True)
df.columns=['test']
df = df.test.str.split(expand=True)
df.rename(columns ={0:'Date', 1:'Time', 2:'Time2', 3:'Pressure', 4:'Temperature'},inplace=True)
df.drop(columns={'Time','Time2'}, inplace=True)

wellname = 'well 4' 
df['Wellbore'] = wellname 

df.set_index('Wellbore', inplace=True)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.resample('D').mean()
```

When I run the code, I get the error "TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'". I'm not sure how to fix this, even after resetting the index. When I set the date column as the index and try resampling, I get a key error. The only way I can get this to work is if I index the date column when reading the file, and deleting the unnecessary first few rows BEFORE importing the file (**but I'd rather not have to do it this way**).

Expected output:

```
 Wellbore        Date       Pressure     Temperature
  Well 4      10/23/2019      13.34        106.1
  Well 4      10/24/2019      13.20        106.2
  Well 4      10/25/2019      13.36        105.9
  Well 4      10/26/2019      13.29        105.9
  Well 4      10/27/2019      13.27        105.8
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output in your question (no images). Please see how to create a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Is this better? @DavidErickson

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `pd.Grouper`. Also, there are a load of parameters with `read_csv` that you can ultilize to save a lot of code:

```
df = (pd.read_csv('well_pressures.txt', sep='', usecols = [0,3,4], skiprows=20,
                 names=['Date', 'Pressure', 'Temperature'], parse_dates=True)
      .assign(Wellbore='well 4')
      .set_index('Date'))
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1D')).mean() #Also, you can try df = df.resample('D').mean() but I think you are looking to groupby day.
df
```